# Extract list elements based on

Tags: python, list

I have a list which looks like this:

```
['48638 0 Q qp32', '48708 0 Q qp32', '48736 0 Q batch', '48737 0 Q batch', '48738 588:30:5 R qp32', '48758 45:00:40 R qp32', '48763 274:19:4 R qp256', '48772 0 Q qp32', '48782 02:25:16 R qp256', '48783 0 Q qp256', '48786 0 Q qp256', '48802 05:57:29 R qp64']
```

How can I extract numbers like `48638` based on parameters like `Q` or `R` and put the output into a separate list? Since this is inside an entire list I am not able to figure out any solution.

Output must be in two separate lists:

- If it has `Q` then it should print `48638, 48708, 48736, 48783, 48786`
- If it has `R` then it should print `48738, 48802, 48782, 48763`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in` membership tests to see if the character is present, then use string splitting to extract the first element:

```
parameter = 'R' # or 'Q'
[s.partition(' ')[0] for s in yourlist if parameter in s]
```

This produces strings (so `['48638', '48708', '48736', '48783', '48786'] for`'Q'`). If you needed *integers*, simply add`int()`:

```
[int(s.partition(' ')[0]) for s in yourlist if parameter in s]
```

Demo:

```
>>> yourlist = ['48638 0 Q qp32', '48708 0 Q qp32', '48736 0 Q batch', '48737 0 Q batch', '48738 588:30:5 R qp32', '48758 45:00:40 R qp32', '48763 274:19:4 R qp256', '48772 0 Q qp32', '48782 02:25:16 R qp256', '48783 0 Q qp256', '48786 0 Q qp256', '48802 05:57:29 R qp64'] 
>>> parameter = 'R'
>>> [s.partition(' ')[0] for s in yourlist if parameter in s]
['48738', '48758', '48763', '48782', '48802']
>>> [int(s.partition(' ')[0]) for s in yourlist if parameter in s]
[48738, 48758, 48763, 48782, 48802]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_numbers(your_list, typ):
    res = []
    for e in your_list:
        ls = e.split()
        if ls[2] == typ:
            res.append(int(ls[0]))
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data=['48638 0 Q qp32', '48708 0 Q qp32', '48736 0 Q batch', '48737 0 Q batch', '48738 588:30:5 R qp32', '48758 45:00:40 R qp32', '48763 274:19:4 R qp256', '48772 0 Q qp32', '48782 02:25:16 R qp256', '48783 0 Q qp256', '48786 0 Q qp256', '48802 05:57:29 R qp64'] 
qs=[int(s.split(' ')[0]) for s in data if 'Q' in s]
rs=[int(s.split(' ')[0]) for s in data if 'R' in s]
```